# Python not updating in while loop

Tags: python, ode, orbital-mechanics

Trying to regularize the equations of motion of a two body system (to update to a three body later on). I've written a RK4 loop and tried it using Newton's equations first for which it worked perfectly. I'm now trying to use a regularization method to get the second order derivative of the position i.e. acceleration. However I only get a flat curve.

```
from __future__ import division 
import numpy as np

from numpy import linalg as LA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve


AU=1.5e11
a=AU
e=0
ms = 2E30
me = 5.98E24
mv=4.867E24
yr=3.15e7
h=100
mu1=ms*me/(ms+me)
mu2=ms*me/(ms+me)
G=6.67E11
#initial velocity
vi=np.sqrt(G*ms*(2/(a*(1-e))-1/a))


#initial position&velocity
sunpos=np.array([0,0,0])
earthpos=np.array([a*(1-e),0,0])


earthv=np.array([0,vi,0])
sunv=np.array([0,0,0])
#magnitude of position vector
norme=sum( (earthpos-sunpos)**2 )**0.5
norma=sum( (sunpos-earthpos)**2 )**0.5

#System of non-linear equations to get regularized position
def equations(p,qf):
    q1, q2, q3, q4 = p
    r1=np.sqrt((qf[0]-mu2)**2+qf[1]**2+qf[2]**2)
    return q1**2-q2**2-q3**2+q4**2-qf[0]+mu2, 2*q1*q2-2*q3*q4-qf[1], 2*q1*q3+2*q2*q4-qf[2], q1**2+q2**2+q3**2+q4**2-r1



#system of non-linear equations to get regularized velocity
def equationsp(pp,qfp,qs):
    dq1, dq2, dq3, dq4 = pp
    D=qs[0]**2+qs[1]**2+qs[2]**2+qs[3]**2
    return 2*(qs[0]*dq1-qs[1]*dq2-qs[2]*dq3+qs[3]*dq4)-D*qfp[0],2*(qs[1]*dq1+qs[0]*dq2-qs[3]*dq3-qs[2]*dq4)-D*qfp[1], 2*(qs[2]*dq1+qs[0]*dq3+qs[3]*dq2+qs[1]*dq4)-D*qfp[2],2*(qs[3]*dq1-qs[2]*dq2+qs[1]*dq3-qs[0]*dq4)



#Actual regularization method to get acceleration
def DotR(qf,dqf):
         r1=np.sqrt((qf[0]-mu2)**2+qf[1]**2+qf[2]**2)
         r2=np.sqrt((qf[0]+mu1)**2+qf[1]**2+qf[2]**2)
         Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4=fsolve(equations, (1, 1, 1, 1),qf)
         qf[0]=Q1**2-Q2**2-Q3**2+Q4**2+mu2
         qf[1]=2*Q1*Q2-2*Q3*Q4
         qf[2]=2*Q1*Q3+2*Q2*Q4
         r1=Q1**2+Q2**2+Q3**2+Q4**2 
         D=4*(Q1**2+Q2**2+Q3**2+Q4**2)
         dQ1,dQ2,dQ3,dQ4=fsolve(equationsp, (1, 1, 1, 1),(dqf,(Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)))
         dq0=2*(Q1*dQ1-Q2*dQ2-Q3*dQ3+Q4*dQ4)
         dq1=2*(Q2*dQ1+Q1*dQ2-Q4*dQ3-Q3*dQ4)
         dD=8*(Q1*dQ1+Q2*dQ2+Q3*dQ3+Q4*dQ4)
         ddq0=(D**3*(qf[0]-mu1/r1**3*(qf[0]-mu2)-mu2/r2**3*(qf[0]+mu1))+dD*dq0+2*D**2*dq1)/D
         ddq1=(D**3*(qf[1]-mu1*qf[1]/r1**3-mu2*qf[1]/r2**2)+dD*dq1+2*D**2*dq0)/D
         ddq2=(D**3*(-mu1*qf[2]/r1**3-mu2*qf[2]/r2**3))/D
         return np.array([ddq0,ddq1,ddq2])
 #initial acceleration    
eartha=G*ms*(earthpos-sunpos)/norme**3
suna=-G*me*(sunpos-earthpos)/norma**3

xarray=[]
yarray=[]
zarray=[]
xarray.append(earthpos[0])
yarray.append(earthpos[1])
zarray.append(earthpos[2])

t=0
T=10**3
#Runge-kutta while loop
while t<T:
    k1v1=h*earthv
    k1v2=h*sunv
    k1a1=h*eartha
    k1a2=h*suna
    earthpos=earthpos+.5*k1v1
    sunpos=sunpos+.5*k1v2
    earthv=earthv+.5*k1a1
    sunv=sunv+.5*k1a2
    norme=sum( (earthpos-sunpos)**2 )**0.5
    norma=sum( (sunpos-earthpos)**2 )**0.5
    print(DotR(earthpos,earthv))
    eartha=DotR(earthpos,earthv)
    suna=DotR(sunpos,sunv)


    k2v1=h*earthv
    k2v2=h*sunv
    k2a1=h*eartha
    k2a2=h*suna
    earthpos=earthpos+.5*k2v1
    sunpos=sunpos+.5*k2v2
    earthv=earthv+.5*k2a1
    sunv=sunv+.5*k2a2
    norme=sum( (earthpos-sunpos)**2 )**0.5
    norma=sum( (sunpos-earthpos)**2 )**0.5
    eartha=DotR(earthpos,earthv)
    suna=DotR(sunpos,sunv)

    k3v1=h*earthv
    k3v2=h*sunv
    k3a1=h*eartha
    k3a2=h*suna
    earthpos=earthpos+k3v1
    sunpos=sunpos+k3v2
    earthv=earthv+k3a1
    sunv=sunv+k3a2
    norme=sum( (earthpos-sunpos)**2 )**0.5
    norma=sum( (sunpos-earthpos)**2 )**0.5
    eartha=DotR(earthpos,earthv)
    suna=DotR(sunpos,sunv)

    k4v1=h*earthv
    k4v2=h*sunv
    k4a1=h*eartha
    k4a2=h*suna
    earthpos=earthpos+h/6.0*(k1v1+2*k2v1+2*k3v1+k4v1)
    sunpos=sunpos+h/6.0*(k1v2+2*k2v2+2*k3v2+k4v2)
    earthv=earthv+h/6.0*(k1a1+2*k2a1+2*k3a1+k4a1)
    sunv=sunv+h/6.0*(k1a2+2*k2a2+2*k3a2+k4a2)
    norme=sum( (earthpos-sunpos)**2 )**0.5
    norma=sum( (sunpos-earthpos)**2 )**0.5
    eartha=DotR(earthpos,earthv)
    suna=DotR(sunpos,sunv)
    xarray.append(earthpos[0])
    yarray.append(earthpos[1])
   # print(earthpos,sunpos)

   # zarray.append(earthpos[2])   
    t=t+h

plt.plot(xarray,yarray)
plt.savefig('orbit.png')
```

The problem seem to be that eartha and suna is not 'updating' when printing I get the same acceleration for each iteration but I'm not sure what could causes this.

Comment: The problem comes from the `fsolve` methods. The both calls in `DotR` always return the same values whatever the input. This [discussion](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/372037-fsolve-not-giving-the-right-answers-for-nonlinear-equation) might help you (yes this is in MatLab code, but the ideas are the same).

Answer (score 0):

As in the earlier question, you are implementing RK4 wrong. The state updates for the stages are **not** cumulative, they are all based on the state as at the start of the step. To compute the second stage use (`T` stands for temporary)

```
    k1v1=h*earthv
    k1v2=h*sunv
    k1a1=h*eartha
    k1a2=h*suna
    earthposT=earthpos+.5*k1v1
    sunposT=sunpos+.5*k1v2
    earthvT=earthv+.5*k1a1
    sunvT=sunv+.5*k1a2
    norme=sum( (earthposT-sunposT)**2 )**0.5
    norma=sum( (sunposT-earthposT)**2 )**0.5
    print(DotR(earthposT,earthvT))
    eartha=DotR(earthposT,earthvT)
    suna=DotR(sunposT,sunvT)


    k2v1=h*earthvT
    k2v2=h*sunvT
    k2a1=h*eartha
    k2a2=h*suna
```

etc. I'm not sure if that is the only error, but with that the RK4 method should be correct.

Comment: Thank you I'll try that, how would the rest of the code look like? WOuld I continue wth the the T in the second step as:               
    k2v1=h*earthvT
    k2v2=h*sunvT
    k2a1=h*eartha
    k2a2=h*suna
    earthposT=earthposT+.5*k2v1
    sunposT=sunposT+.5*k2v2
    earthvT=earthvT+.5*k2a1
    sunvT=sunvT+.5*k2a2
    norme=sum( (earthposT-sunposT)**2 )**0.5
    norma=sum( (sunposT-earthposT)**2 )**0.5
    eartha=DotR(earthposT,earthvT)
    suna=DotR(sunposT,sunvT)    and the same for the 3rd and 4th?

Comment: Yes, that then applies for all 4 stages, resp. the 3 non-trivial ones. You might also want to start separating model and solver so you can switch out solvers. That would require functions in the model that transform the state into a flat array, and reversely read the state from a flat array. You could base the model then on a flat array and have its vectors be pointers/views into that array.